# Use Python to create 2D coordinate with particular grid

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new user of python, mainly working with geodata and ML techniques. The question is bit strange, maybe there are a lot of geo-related python packages, but now I am struggling to create 2D coordinates of drill holes.

So, creation of vertical lines of coordinates is easy by using append function, however I need a different angled lines along the coordinates. So, this code bellow is for vertical lines.

Coordinates of  small scale region are
min X = 3200 Y = 1050
max X = 3600 Y = 1250

```
minX = 3200
minY = 1050
maxX = 3600
maxY = 1250

# 15 meter difference is taken (reason = just to check) between drill holes and 1 m is an interval

coordinate_2D = coordinate = []
coordinate = []
x = minX
y = minY

while y < maxY:
    x = minX
    while x < maxX:
        coordinate.append((x,y))
        x += 15
    coordinate.append((x,y))
    y += 1
    
print(coordinate)
```

and the plot looks like this  [image_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJHYt.png)

But, I need angled lines, (60 degree will be good, but if the angle is changeable by code, it is better).

May be you have any suggestions? Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you use trigonometrics functions you could change the coordinate correctly by doing this:

```
from math import cos, sin, sqrt
import numpy as np
#alpha your angle in radiant! 
#so if you want to change degree to radiants do this 
# alpha = alpha * 180/np.pi

x = x + y/(maxY*tan(alpha))*sqrt(x**2 +y**2)
```